# "Just waiting for" or "waiting just for"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have found both on the Internet. Which one is correct? If both are, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: You should include the examples that you found on the Internet for context. Either could be the correct choice depending on what the sentence is trying to convey.

Comment: Not sure why I should add an example. I am asking for general rules, not for a correction of 1 specific sentence. What does "just waiting for" and "waiting just for" mean, are both correct, where to use them?

Comment: Just waiting - talks about waiting; ...just for - talks about the reason.  In other words, what immediately follows 'just' gets the influence of it.

Comment: You should add an example because the appropriateness of one form or the other may depend on the context!

Comment: @KateBunting Are you saying that there are no general rules?

Comment: Often, we say "I am just waiting for something" to mean that is all I am doing, and not anything else, whereas "I am waiting just for something" generally means I am waiting only for that thing.

Comment: 1. A policeman asks me why I am standing around. I can say "I'm just waiting for a bus" (and not e.g. loitering with intent to rob). 2. At a party someone says "I hope plenty of people come", and I might say "I'm waiting just for Mary to arrive" (I don't care who else comes).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of the word ‘just’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217019/position-of-the-word-just)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth no, unfortunately it's actually a different usage of "just", that does not correspond to my question. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think @MichaelHarvey 's comments is the answer I need

Comment: "I am just waiting for Mary" is often used with the sense "I am waiting for Mary and nobody else" too. And, confusingly, with the implication "I'm waiting for Mary; don't worry about me getting cold or anything ... I'll be along/going home soon." // Context and intonation are very important when decoding how these _limiting modifiers_ (even, just, only, merely, almost, hardly, simply, alone, also ...) are being used.